# How to see what is cached in memory in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory

Is there a way how to find out what is cached in SQL Server 2008 R2? I have found the following nice article: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/17/sql-server-data-pages-in-buffer-pool-data-stored-in-memory-cache . However, I would like to know how much data (e.g. in percentage and KB) are stored of each table and index. Is there some simple way how to obtain such data?

Answer (score 17):

You can find whats stored in the buffer pool (data cache) using below query :

From [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160229195711/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlperf/archive/2007/05/18/bufferpooldatapagesbreakdown.aspx) :

```
select
       count(*)as cached_pages_count,
       obj.name as objectname,
       ind.name as indexname,
       obj.index_id as indexid
from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors as bd
    inner join
    (
        select       object_id as objectid,
                           object_name(object_id) as name,
                           index_id,allocation_unit_id
        from sys.allocation_units as au
            inner join sys.partitions as p
                on au.container_id = p.hobt_id
                    and (au.type = 1 or au.type = 3)
        union all
        select       object_id as objectid,
                           object_name(object_id) as name,
                           index_id,allocation_unit_id
        from sys.allocation_units as au
            inner join sys.partitions as p
                on au.container_id = p.partition_id
                    and au.type = 2
    ) as obj
        on bd.allocation_unit_id = obj.allocation_unit_id
left outer join sys.indexes ind 
  on  obj.objectid = ind.object_id
 and  obj.index_id = ind.index_id
where bd.database_id = db_id()
  and bd.page_type in ('data_page', 'index_page')
group by obj.name, ind.name, obj.index_id
order by cached_pages_count desc
```

Excellent reference : [Inside the Storage Engine: What’s in the buffer pool?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-whats-in-the-buffer-pool/) by Paul Randal.

Answer (score 5):

You can use dynamic management view to list currently cached pages and filter them by database_id:

```
   select top 100 * from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
```

Then you can see `DBCC PAGE` command to list pages of an object. Good reference: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1578/using-dbcc-page-to-examine-sql-server-table-and-index-data/

It'll be up to you, however, to combine the results, and it doesn't seem an easy task :). Let us know when you come up with effective way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL query:

```
select count(*)*8/1024 AS 'Cached Size (MB)'        
,case database_id                
when 32767 then 'ResourceDB'                
else db_name(database_id)                
end as 'Database'
from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
where page_type in
(
'INDEX_PAGE'
,'DATA_PAGE'
)
group by db_name(database_id), database_id
order by 'Cached Size (MB)' desc
```